# Getting expected value of future value with time varying data (credit card revolving and fee data) . Customer lifetime value

Tags: r, time-series, probability

I have a credit card data and that contains monthly amount of revolving and amount of fee for each customer. As a bank perspective, I want to get the expected value of future revolving amount and fee amount in total (by using discount factor in infinite time horizon).
I want to get the expected future value of revolving and fee respectively.
The one way of my idea is that
 E(future) = Sum [ {prob(revolving at time t)*amount of revolving at time t} / {(1+discount)^t} ]

Very simply we can think (revolving case)
 probability of revolving at time t = x/n (where x is number of revolving in data and n is total month in data)
 amount of revolving at time = mean of amount of revolving in data (constant)

Actually I want to estimates the present value of expected future values. but above way is too naive.
Is there any good idea that I can estimate the future value of revolving and fee values with monthly timeseries data ? (I have other variables like demographic, creditcard usage history and others).
Thanks.
I prefer R for program. Any suggestion with R package ?

Answer (score 0):

People generally like the "zoo" and "forecast" packages in R for time series, but R does some simple time series stuff without any packages.  If you want to learn more about time series prediction in R, Cowpertwait's "Introductory Time Series with R" is a really good book.  I'd recommend going through it to learn how to do the kind of modeling with time series you want.